# Providing users with a way to detag their Facebook photos

Tags: facebook, tagging

I run a social membership club and my website users can log into my site with each having their own profile page.

On each of my user's profile pages, I want to display a list of photos which have been tagged with that user on Facebook. I know this part is possible.

The bit I am struggling with is giving each of my users the ability to 'untag' themselves in each photo of them that is displayed in the list. The 'untagging' should happen directly from my site. Is this possible and how could I go about doing this?

Hope someone can help/has ideas?

Comment: Note that the [tag:untagged] tag is an internal tag which gets added when the Question loses its existing tags, not one to be actually used for a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no facbeook API that allows removal of photo tags at this time of writing.

Answer (score -1):

Its not documented and I haven't tested this but I'd chance issuing a DELTE request to

/PHOTO_ID/tags/USER_ID

Worth a shot through the graph explorer anyway.